# PHP/JQUERY- Can't return data from a query

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I'm doing a project for an exam. I'm stuck with that and I hope someone of you could help me (I'm italian, so sorry for my bad english!).
I have to query an existing database stored in phpmyadmin with a PHP script. Then, the query result need to be parsed with a jquery script and printed to an HTML page.
Here is the PHP script:

```
    <?php
     $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
     if (!$con) {
       die('Errore di connessione: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysql_select_db("progetto_lpw", $con);

     $sql="SELECT denominazione FROM farmacia";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

     $num=mysql_numrows($result);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         print json_encode($row['denominazione']);
         print "<br />";
      }
      ?>
```

I've already tested the PHP script calling it via browser and it works.

Then, I parse the result with this jquery script (the use of this combination is a requirement of the project):

```
$("#button").click(function(){

 $.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(index,value){

                $("#xx").append("<p>"+value+"</p>")
                })
            })
})
```

Here is the problem: when I open the HTML page and I click the button on firefox, consolle says "no element found" referring to PHP script.

"xx" is the id of the div in which elements are printed.

Where is the error?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Not sure I get it, does it say 404 File not found, or does it actually say "no element found" ?

Comment: It say "no element found"..maybe I wrong something in jquery script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace below code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print json_encode($row['denominazione']);
    print "<br />";
}
```

With below code and try

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row['denominazione'];
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">Fetch JSON</button>
<div id="xx"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $("#xx").append("<p>" + value + "</p>")
        });
    });
});
```

Response from `json.php` should be in below format

```
["AGGERI","ALCHEMICA 1961"]
```

The reason your code isn't working is that it's producing output like this:

```
"foo"<br />
"bar"<br />
```

That's not valid [JSON](http://json.org). To be valid, you have to *not* have the HTML `<br />` in there (this is JSON, not HTML), and you have to have commas between the elements you want to return.

`json_encode` will handle formatting the array correctly for you.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Kra62/1/)** with post request to send and get `json` output

Comment: +1 It's best, though, to *explain* why you've suggested the change you've suggested. I've added an explanation for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for explanation, I also added `HTML` markup and `JS` in answer

Comment: Have you added `HTML` markup as suggested above and make sure `jQuery` reference is added. If yes then what error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the code as you suggest. 
On FF, when I open the web consolle there's this error message:"no element found", referring to the PHP script.
I've put the folder with scripts and HTML page in xampp/phpmyadmin/test, with Apache and MySql running. Could be a problem?

Comment: Sorry for the repost, but maybe this could help: running the php script in the browser, query result is like this:

[{"0":"AGGERI","denominazione":"AGGERI"},{"0":"ALCHEMICA 1961","denominazione":"ALCHEMICA 1961"}, and so on..]

what is the correct way to parse it with json?

Comment: Answer updated, Replaced `$rows[] = $row;` with `$rows[] = $row['denominazione'];`, Added response format from `json.php` and jsFiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

'print' works differently then 'echo'. At least i am sending JSON packages with echo from php.
Can you replace it ?

```
// in php
echo json_encode($row['denominazione']);

// in jquery script, best to place "<br />" tag here
$("#xx").append("<p>"+value+"</p><br />")
```

Comment: This isn't the OP's fundamental problem.